# For each site, find unique number of users whose last visit was to that site

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, distinct

given the table of the following:
timestamp, user, site_id

For each site, I want to find the number of unique users whose last visit was to that site.

I found the number of unique users per site. 
but does not correspond the last login and user can be unique in each site..

```
SELECT site_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM SWE
GROUP BY site_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: i am using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You could use a correlated subquery here:

```
SELECT site_id, COUNT(*) AS unique_cnt
FROM SWE s1
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM SWE s2
                   WHERE s1.user_id = s2.user_id AND s1.site_id = s2.site_id)
GROUP BY site_id;
```

The subquery finds, for each user and site, the maximum (most recent) timestamp for that combination.  Only records having the most recent timestamp for a given user and site are considered in the distinct count.

Comment: Thanks i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the last visit and a check on the site:

```
select site, count(*)
from t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.user = t.user
                    ) 
group by site;
```

In Postgres, I would be inclined to use `distinct on`:

```
select site, count(*)
from (select distinct on (user) t.*
      from t
      order by user, timestamp desc
     ) t
group by site;
```